# Comando para abrir gaveta de dinheiro

Tags: c#

Estou tentando fazer um botão que envia um comando para abrir a gaveta de dinheiro ligada a impressora Tanca TP-650. Segue abaixo o método que estou tentando.

```
    public static void abrirGaveta(bool flag)
    {
        if (flag == true && Properties.Settings.Default.ImpressoraGaveta == 1)
        {
            //Metoto para abrir a gaveta


            const int charCode = 27;
            const int charCode2 = 251;
            const int charCode3 = 227;
            var specialChar = Convert.ToChar(charCode);
            var specialChar2 = Convert.ToChar(charCode2);
            var specialChar3 = Convert.ToChar(charCode3);
            string cmdText = "" + specialChar + specialChar2 +"22|" + specialChar3;

            string driver = "TANCA TP-650";
            string comandoAbertura = cmdText;
            RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(driver, comandoAbertura);
        }
    }
```

Não acusa erro nenhum, porém, também não abre a gaveta.

Comment: Tem a certeza que está a enviar o código correto para isso?

Comment: então, esse já tentei com diversos códigos que fui achando na internet. Estou na esperança de que alguém aqui tenha feito.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada ao exemplo em C# que eles têm na página? http://www.tanca.com.br/drivers.php?cat=19&sub=54

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
            public static void abrirGaveta(bool flag)
    {
        if (flag == true && Properties.Settings.Default.ImpressoraGaveta == 1)
        {

            string driver = "TANCA TP-650";
            string comandoAbertura = "\u001bp\0\nd";
            RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(driver, comandoAbertura);
        }
    }
```

o erro estava no código (char) na variável comandoAbertura.